# Browser not handling exception from AJAX panel, ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax, exception

i am having trouble catching errors in an AJAX panel. Even when i throw an exception in the c# code behind the front end completely ignores it.

Here is the code i have setup, can anyone see why?

I ideally want to show a js alert window on error.

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void btnX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("test");
}

protected void ScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = e.Exception.Message;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, e)
    {
       window.alert(e.get_error().name);
    }
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="true" OnAsyncPostBackError="ScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be displaying the 'message' error property and not 'name'

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, e)
{
    if (e.get_error() != undefined)
    {
     var errorMessage = e.get_error().message;
     e.set_errorHandled(true);
     alert(errorMessage)
    }
}
```